# Как найти медиану

Tags: java, массивы, list

```
    List<Object> sorted = listValue.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
    int middle = listValue.size()/ 2;
    int medianValue = 0; 
    if (listValue.size() % 2 == 1)
        medianValue = (int) listValue.get(middle);
    else
        medianValue = (int)(listValue.get(middle - 1) + listValue.get(middle)) / 2;
Выдаёт ошибку в последней строке: `medianValue = (int)(listValue.get(middle - 1) + listValue.get(middle)) / 2;`, т.к. с Object нельзя использовать +, и при запуске программы компилятор выдаёт ошибку здесь `medianValue = (int) listValue.get(middle);`, такая ошибка: `java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer` Буду благодарна за помощь!

**UPD**
Отредактировала, привела к инту, но теперь рассчитывается неправильно
   

     List<Object> listValue = getValueFromColumnByRow(2);
        List<Object> sorted = listValue.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(x -> Integer.parseInt(Objects.toString(x))))            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    int middle = listValue.size()/ 2;
    int medianValue = 0;
    int m = Integer.parseInt((String) listValue.get(middle - 1));
    if (listValue.size() % 2 == 1)
        medianValue = Integer.parseInt((String) listValue.get(middle));
    else
        medianValue = (m + medianValue) / 2;
```

Comment: почему в первой половине ифа вы значение приводите к инту, а во второй вы решили сначала просуммировать объекты. поделить результат и только потом привести к целому? Компилятор, в целом правильно озабоченность свою высказывает, складывать надо числа иа не объекты, а для этого приводить к инту надо слагаемые, а не сумму

Comment: Отредактировала код, посмотрите, в чём ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, медиана имеет смысл для *отсортированного* списка.

Во-вторых, расчёт медианы во втором примере (после редактирования) некорректен, достаточно было преобразовать тип и обработать случай чётного количества элементов в списке:

```java
int middle = sorted.size()/ 2;
int medianValue = Integer.parseInt(sorted.get(middle).toString()); 
if (listValue.size() % 2 == 0) {
    medianValue = (medianValue + Integer.parseInt(sorted.get(middle - 1).toString())) / 2;
}
```

Comment: Хоть я уже и сама разобралась, поняла где были ошибки, спасибо!